# DB2: Changing current schema doesn't show tables in that schema

Tags: database, db2, schema, db2-luw

DB2 on Linux.

I have two schemas in my database (say `AAA` and `BBB`),

I find the current schema by,

```
db2 values current schema
```

> AAA

I can find list of tables in this schema by

```
db2 list tables
```

Now I change the current schema with

```
db2 set schema  BBB
```

But, now when I list the tables again, it still shows old list, even though I know there are different tables in schema BBB. Just out of curiosity I tried to see the structure of tables by

```
db2 describe table tab_name_1
```

this returns empty result as long as the current schema is BBB, where as if I change the current schema to AAA, I can see the full structure of tables.

I am very new to DB2, so I may be wrong, bu this behaviour doesn't look right to me. I was expecting to see tables in current schema when queried.

I would appreciate if someone can shed light on this or provide some good source.

Answer (score 0):

The list tables syntax has the USER as the default.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001967.html

The current schema would apply to sql statements. "LIST TABLES" and "DESCRIBE TABLE" are db2 commands and not sql statements.